# How to modify / delete keys the AppConfig file

Tags: c#, app-config

My question is regarding the AppConfig file. Basically I know how to retrieve the keys and values, but the question here is how can I delete the key and values or modify the values on a runtime?

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="key1" value="value1" />
  <add key="key2" value="value2" />
  <add key="key3" value="value3" />
</appSettings>
```

**So what if I want to modify:**

And I want to have `key1` with value set to `Test` so that I have `<add key="key1" value="Test" />`

**And what if I want to delete;**

Let presume I want to delete `key3` to remove it from appSettings,

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Do you want your edits to get saved back to the file or you just want changes till current application runtime and use the default when loaded again ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
 m_Configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
 m_Configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key);
 m_Configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
 m_Configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add System.Configuration assembly

then do some sort of work like

```
Configuration config =  ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("currentApppath");
            AppSettingsSection section = config.GetSection("appsettings");
            section.Settings.Add .......
```

Comment: hmm a how do i create a new section for my app? because this is config is being used by many applications )

Comment: Try it first on some sample application.When you are aware of this simple Configuration api's usage then i am sure you can implement it easily in your application.Marek has provided little bit of more detail about how to use it below